# Null-coalescing operator "??" not catching a database null value that is a foreign key

Tags: c#, exception, null, operators

I have a simple C# statement:

```
var code = container.thing.result.decode ?? "Unknown";
```

That throws an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." exception when the database value is null. It works perfectly (so far) with non-null values. I tried being more explicit and rewrote the line with a ternary operator:

```
var outcome = container.thing.result.decode == null ? "Unknown" : container.thing.result.decode;
```

And I get the same result with the same exception (and ReSharper guides me back to the much simpler ?? statement).

I also read that the ?? operator only works with nullable types. The field I'm working with is not a nullable type, it's an nvarchar(100) and also a foreign key to a lookup table. As I said above, the statement works with a valid non-null value.

The application's ORM also has a CODE value, to make a CODE and DECODE pair, which looks like it maps to the lookup table as it should.

But I can't figure out how to deal with null values.

Thank you!

EDIT: Thank you for the quick responses! I did figure out where I was confused only minutes after posting. I think writing the question out helped me delineate the problem. I changed the statement to check if the actual field referencing the lookup table is null:

```
var outcome = container.thing.database_code_field == null ? "Unknown" : container.thing.result.Decode;
```

This looks like what I want. Thank you again!

Comment: What is null? Is it the `result` part or `thing` part? This exception probably raise for something else (not `decode`).

Comment: Yes, thank you, I think I came to the same conclusions as below only a few minutes after posting this question. I love it when that happens. If I change the statement to "var outcome = container.thing.code == null ? "Unknown" : container.thing.result.decode;" I get what I want. It makes sense to me now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll get an exception if *any* of the following is null:

- `container`
- `container.thing`
- `container.thing.result`

We can't tell which of those values is null in your situation, or whether null is a valid value. You should work that out and then either fix whatever's giving you a null value, or write code to handle that case.

Answer (score 4):

You need to step through your entire member hierarchy.

For example, if `container` is null, then you cannot access `container.thing`. And if `container.thing` is null, you cannot access `container.thing.results`, etc.

It is not enough to simply catch the case where the very last member is null.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `container`, `thing`, or `result` is null, not `decode`.  If `decode` was null then the `??` operator would set the string appropriately.

`??` is a function that takes some nullable value and a non-null value to replace it.  The entire left hand side of the `??` operator needs to be evaluated to pass it into that function, and if one of the previously mentioned variables is null it doesn't even get that far.